# Adjoint maps in the 2-category of topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, adjoint-functors

The category of topological spaces has a 2-category structure, in which the objects are topological spaces, morphisms are continuous maps and 2-morphisms are homotopy classes of homotopies. Therefore, we can ask what it means for two morphisms to be "adjoint" to one another. In this case, one works out that a pair of continuous maps $f: X \to Y, g: Y \to X $ are adjoint to one another if there exist homotopies $H: id_X \simeq g\circ f$ and $K: f\circ g \simeq id_Y$ such that
$$f(H(x,t)) = f(x),\quad H(g(y),t)=g(y) \text{ for } x\in X,y\in Y,0\leq t\leq 1/2$$
and
$$K(f(x),2t-1) = f(x),\quad g(K(y,2t-1))=g(y) \text{ for } x\in X,y\in Y,1/2\leq t\leq 1$$

Has this concept been studied? Does it go by another name? I don't have any non-trivial examples and a quick google search hasn't turned anything up, so I'm not sure whether or not it's a concept of interest.

---

More specifically, the 2-category structure is as follows:
Let $f,g,h: X \to Y $ be continuous maps and $H: f \simeq g $, $K:  g \simeq h$
be homotopies. Then the vertical composition of $H,K$ is given by
$$K\circ H: I \times X \to Y$$
$$(K\circ H)(x,t) = H(x,t) \text{ if } 0\leq t\leq 1/2 $$
$$(K\circ H)(x,t) = K(x,2t-1) \text{ if } 1/2\leq t\leq 1 $$

Similarly, if $X \xrightarrow{f,f'} Y \xrightarrow{g,g'} Z$ are continuous maps and $H: f \simeq f' $, $K:  g \simeq g'$ are homotopies, then the vertical composition of $H,K$ is
$$K\ast H: I\times X \to Z $$
$$(K \ast H)(x,t) = K(H(x,t),t) $$

Comment: Your vertical composition is not associative.

Comment: @ZhenLin This is what I get for not checking the axioms of a 2-category carefully. Hopefully it is still a non-strict 2-category, but I don't know enough about those to check

Comment: You need to work with track classes of homotopies, rather than the homotopies themselves. The tool you need is called Vogt's Lemma.

Comment: @Tyrone what do you mean by "track classes of homotopies"? Also, I'm not entirely sure how Vogt's Lemma helps here - it tells me that any spaces which are homotopy equivalent are "adjoint equivalent" (which indeed follows from the abstract nonsense of 2-categories), but my question is what "adjointness" means when the spaces are not neccesarily homotopy equivalent

Comment: The traditional way of making a 2-category of topological spaces with homotopies gives a (2, 1)-category, in which case adjoints are the same as equivalences. There are other options, but in the end you have a homotopy between $\textrm{id}$ and $g \circ f$ and a homotopy between $f \circ g$ and $\textrm{id}$, so every adjoint is a homotopy equivalence, at least.

Comment: You do need some fix for the vertical composition, regardless. It is associative in any 2-category, strict or otherwise.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ah, I hadn't realised that thr invertibility of the 2-morphisms means that adjointness immediately implies adjoint equivalence. By the way, what is this "traditional" way?

Comment: I said nothing about invertibility in general. In the traditional way (which Tyrone alluded to) the 2-cells are invertible. There are other ways which do not make the 2-cells invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, we have homotopies $H: id_X \simeq g \circ f$ and $K: f \circ g \simeq id_Y$, the maps $f,g$ constitute a homotopy equivalence (in particular an adjoint equivalence). But a well-known fact about 2-categories is that any pair of objects which are equivalent are in fact adjoint equivalent. So the notion of two spaces being adjoint is the same as them being homotopy equivalent. Hence, the notion of adjointness is not very interesting.